# mediawiki mathjax need to use escape $x$

Tags: mediawiki, mathjax

I am using MediaWiki with MathJax, because a lot of the pages have maths equations. But on some pages I also need to display the string $x$ as is.

Is there any way to escape the $x$ so it doesn't invoke MathJax and display as an italic x?

MathJax supports \$ to escape a $ within an expression, but that doesn't work with the initial $ (of course).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set `processEscapes:true` in the `tex2jax` section of your configuration, then you will be able to escape the initial dollar sign to allow you to type `$x$`.  Alternatively, you can use `<span class="tex2jax_ignore">...</span>` around the text you don't want MathJax to process.  Perhaps easier would be to use `<code>...</code>` around the `$x$`, since MathJax doesn't process text inside code blocks.

Davide

Comment: Thanks, I went for the <span> option because it isn't something I would need to do very often so I prefer to keep the change local rather than changing config files. Works well!