# Pandas - format of values

Tags: pandas, format

Here is my [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e31dlfaeiy1smi/format.csv?dl=0), which I read in to pandas dataframe using `read_csv`.

```
import pandas as pd
df_from =pd.read_csv(r'some path')
```

if you look the file column ('NetworthIndicator_Rollup') values look good, but when I display dataframe in Jupyter or plot heatmap, some of the index values are not correctly formatted. Here is preview of incorrect formatting:[image: incorrect formatting]

In particular 'NetworthIndicator_Rollup' is missing spaces. However when I execute: `df_from['NetworthIndicator_Rollup']`, everything looks good:

[image: just a column]

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you have a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089089/escaping-dollar-sign-in-ipython-notebook