# Display String in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

In a Jupyter Notebook, I have the following code:

```
test = {'cashtag': ['$ text here $ this is a test $ TEST $:']}
dft = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test)
display(dft)
```

The output from this results in:

[Click to see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBbO9.png)

> ℎ  this is a test   :

As shown, for some reason all cashtags are gone and the leftover text is in Italic.
How do I get the text to display exactly as originally typed (with cashtags, no italic)?

----EDIT:

This seems to happen because iPython interprets anything between dollar signs as a MathJax expression.

An easy solution would be to place two backslashes before '$' (\\$).
However, the real dataset I'm working with has tens of millions of rows and possibly hundreds of millions of '$'. Writing code to place '\' before every '$' would severely impact performance.

Is there any way to fix this issue in a 'root' level, preventing iPython to interpret '$' as MathJax in all circumstances?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089089/escaping-dollar-sign-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: @Mike67, thank you your help. However, I don't think the solution above is appropriate in my situation. I have made an edit to the original question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved using:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.html.use_mathjax = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to strip '$' before parsing your data. In pandas, '$' may put you into a position where your DataFrame treats other numeric values as strings, causing problematic issues if you want to use numeric values for data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is being treated as a formatting instruction to display in *italics*

```
test = {'cashtag': ['$ text here \ this is a test $ TEST $:'.replace("$","\$")]}
dft = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test)
display(dft)
```