# pandas/JupyterLab hiding first half of string between $$

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

```
            one          two        three
0  $97500_$9500  $9000_$7500          nan
1  $97500_$9500  $9000_$7500         7000
2  $97500_$9500  $9000_$7500         7000
3  $97500_$9500  $9000_$7500         7000
4  $97500_$9500  $9000_$9900  $7500_$7000
5         97500        77500         7000
6          7700         7000         7000
7          9000         7500          nan
8          9000         7500         7000
9          9500         7500         7000
```

When I display this pandas dataframe in Jupterlab, it appears like this, with hidden values in boxes between the columns:

[image]

It's obviously the bracketing with the two `$` that's making this happen, but I can't find this anywhere in the documentation. Has anyone run into this before? What's the purpose of the functionality?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089089/escaping-dollar-sign-in-ipython-notebook answer your question? I found it by putting `jupyterlab dollar sign` into a search engine. Seeing mention there of `MathJax`, I tried searching again for `jupyterlab mathjax` and found [this documentation](https://nocomplexity.com/documents/jupyterlab/notebooks/TypesettingEquations.html).

Comment: So the implication is the dataframe output in JupyterLab is generated with markdown/LaTeX?

Comment: whoaaaaaa... yeah this is blowing my mind. it does seem to be rendering markdown and also seems buggy. I'm using jupyterlab '3.0.18' and this renders `pd.DataFrame({'A': ['$\alpha$']})` as *lpha*.

Comment: oh oops that was just my dumb failure to escape a backslash. anyway... yeah this is a pandas interacting with jupyter rendering issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a [display option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/options.html) `display.html.use_mathjax` which is `True` by default:

> When True, Jupyter notebook will process table contents using MathJax, rendering mathematical expressions enclosed by the dollar symbol.

You can change this with [`pd.set_option('display.html.use_mathjax', False)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html). This would disable automatic mathjax styling in pandas.

Alternatively, you could try to change the styling. See this issue referencing a similar situation: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40318

Answer (score 0):

Hack

```py
# Data preparing
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from numpy import nan
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'one': {0: '$97500_$9500',1: '$97500_$9500',2: '$97500_$9500',3: '$97500_$9500',4: '$97500_$9500',5: '97500',6: '7700',7: '9000',8: '9000',9: '9500'},'two': {0: '$9000_$7500',1: '$9000_$7500',2: '$9000_$7500',3: '$9000_$7500',4: '$9000_$9900',5: '77500',6: '7000',7: '7500',8: '7500',9: '7500'},'three': {0: nan,1: '7000',2: '7000',3: '7000',4: '$7500_$7000',5: '7000',6: '7000',7: nan,8: '7000',9: '7000'}})

# A hack
>>> df = df.apply(lambda x:x.str.replace("$", "\$"))
>>> df
```

[image]