# $ sign changing structure of markdown table in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a table as follows:

```
| Day | Forecasted Price |
| --- | ---------------- |
| 1   | $ 27,708.42|
| 2   | $ 27,769.91|
| 3   | $ 27,702.45|
| 4   | $ 27,935.59|
| 5   | $ 28,184.62|
| 6   | $ 28,540.08|
| 7   | $ 28,429.97|
```

When I render it in jupyter, I get an output as follows:

[jupyter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VPmZ.png)

When I remove the $ sign from the price though, it works as intended. What could be the case here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping dollar sign in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089089/escaping-dollar-sign-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: Specifically "Simply replace the `$` with `&#36;`"

Comment: It does. Thank you!