# Is it possible to turn Mathjax off in Pandas and/or Jypyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, mathjax

It has already been discussed here that Mathjax interprets dollar sign `$` as start of its code. String within Pandas dataframes when rendered in Jupyter Notebook get garbled if they contain a dollar sign.

Official docs at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html suggest that mathjax in pandas can be disabled by switches:

`pd.set_option('display.html.use_mathjax', False)`

`pd.set_option('styler.html.mathjax', False)`

I turned both options off - and nothing changed, my notebook still displayed large bold italic font without spaces after dollar signs.

By trial and error I figured out that mathjax formatting disappears only if column width is set to less than 135. What is more, only selected cells are formatted: of two cells in the same row that contain the same strings first is plain text, second is mathjax'ed. In the same column, top row triggers mathjax, bottom does not. Compare these two dataframe views.

Mathjax starts formatting top right text field `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 135)`

[image: Dataframe with colwidth of 135]

Mathjax does not format text field  `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 134)`

[image: Dataframe with colwidth of 134]

So it appears that mathjax for dataframe cannot be turned off in Jupyter Notebook by pandas option.

Has anyone dealt with that problem, and is there any way to kill mathjax completely?

UPD Running Jupyter notebook 7.0.6, pandas 2.1.4.

Comment: Those weird things about the column width causing differences seems to be a bug **maybe**. You'll need to specify exact versions of the Jupyter tech and Pandas you are using for your post to be helpful. For example if you are using outdated things, it may have been fixed already. That's just one scenario idea. Who knows what it will be but how to pursue this is limited without that information. In general, in posting in this kind of forum those kinds of details are things you want to include when posting.

Comment: Jupyter notebook 7.0.6, pandas 2.1.4. Probably one month old. Updated post.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't able to find an open issue that looked pertinent.  [This reply](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40318#issuecomment-794214827) to a different, but potentially related issue may be pertinent though. I wonder if doubling the dollar signs would solve your issue? If you had a input for a dataframe as TSV or CSV that shows the issue, I could see if doubling the dollar signs eliminates it. Plus [the original discussion for adding the enhancement](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19824) may give you other ideas to try possibly.

Comment: Thanks. I will not change my data to fix a style issue. Since pandas settings are ignored, I think the problem is entirely on Jupyter Notebook level. Will look at your links to see if there are any fixes for JN.

Comment: Never mind about that one idea actually now that I tried it. [That and the next one there](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40318#issuecomment-794214827) seem to insure it makes MathJax. I think that was the point of that post to make it actually display Latex and not be inconsistent. Opposite of yours. However, what I thought it was meant to do is possible, I think. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53228544/8508004) you can put double blackslashes in front of the dollar signs in your dataframe. It wouldn't be touching your data if you do it right. So either you consider ...

Comment: <contontinued> your data the source data where it is stored, or save your current dataframe it as a TSV or CSV before to get the same pure data available. Or you make a deepcopy of the dataframe that you use for displaying where you do find and replace for all the dollar signs to be `\\$`. Then you have a dataframe that is for display and one for the real data. That post though does explain the width thing though at least. If you get the dollar signs off the same line than Juptyer doesn't read them as the latex symbols.